# The issue with Pylance expecting an expression or "." or "(" not being closed is likely due to syntax errors in my code, but where?

Tags: python, pylance, avcapturedevice

Someone suggested this but it DOESN'T work either.

In the line **AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess (for: .video)**, the parenthesis around for: **.video** should be removed as it is not a valid syntax in Python. Instead, you should separate the keyword argument for and its value .video with a comma.

In the line **AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus**, the dot notation is not correct. You should use the square brackets notation to access the authorizationStatus attribute of the AVCaptureDevice class.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from AVFoundation import AVCaptureDevice

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera=0):
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in
            if granted:
                self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camera)
                self.valid = False
                try:
                    resp = self.cam.read()
                    self.shape = resp[1].shape
                    self.valid = True
                except:
                    self.shape = None
            else:
                print("Permission to access camera was denied.")
                self.valid = False
        }

    def get_frame(self):
        if self.valid:
            _, frame = self.cam.read()
        else:
            frame = np.ones((480, 640, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
            col = (0, 256, 256)
            cv2.putText(frame, "(Error: Camera not accessible)",
                        (65, 220), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, col)
        return frame

    def release(self):
        self.cam.release()
```

Help me to resolve this "syntax error" so I can compile the code to execute a functional py2app.

Comment: You forgot to paste the complete error message.

Comment: `AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in` this line is nothing like valid Python.  What is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: The AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) method is used to request access to the camera from the user. The method takes a completion handler block as an argument, which is executed when the request is completed. The completion handler block is passed a boolean value, "granted", which indicates whether the user granted access to the camera or not. The block of code inside the curly braces is executed based on the value of "granted". If "granted" is True, the camera is initialized and set to self.cam. If "granted" is False, a message is printed and self.valid is set to False. {ObjectiveC}

Comment: Python doesn't use curly braces to delimit blocks of code, unlike other languages such as Javascript or C.  Consider working through the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) to familiarise yourself with the syntax.